# I'm trying to condense my code with while loops in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
#  I have imprted numpy as np previously
print("This is a 2x2 matrix calculator")
a = float(input("Enter the number of the first matrix element of matrix 1: "))
b = float(input("Enter the number of the second matrix element of matrix 1: "))
c = float(input("Enter the number of the third matrix element of matrix 1: "))
d = float(input("Enter the number of the fourth matrix element of matrix 1: "))

a1 = float(input("Enter the number of the first matrix element of matrix 2: "))
b1 = float(input("Enter the number of the second matrix element of matrix 2: "))
c1 = float(input("Enter the number of the third matrix element of matrix 2: "))
d1 = float(input("Enter the number of the fourth matrix element of matrix 2: "))

m = np.array([[a, b], [c, d]])
n = np.array([[a1, b1], [c1, d1]])
det1 = np.linalg.det(m)
det2 = np.linalg.det(n)
dot1 = np.vdot(m, n)
dot2 = np.vdot(n, m)
mat_product1 = np.matmul(m, n)
mat_product2 = np.matmul(n, m)
m_inv = np.linalg.inv(m)
n_inv = np.linalg.inv(n)
solve1 = np.dot(m_inv, n)
solve2 = np.dot(n_inv, m)

print("Matrix 1: ")
print(m)
print("Matrix 2: ")
print(n)
```

The code continues on (and the same for 3x3 matrices)  but my problem comes in when I try this:

```
print("This is a 2x2 matrix calculator")
matrix1 = []
while True:
    element1 = float(input("Enter the matrix numbers for matrix 1, one by one: "))
    matrix1.append(element1)
    if len(matrix1) == 4:
        break
matrix2 = []
while True:
    element2 = float(input("Enter the matrix numbers for matrix 2, one by one: "))
    matrix2.append(element2)
    if len(matrix2) == 4:
        break
m = np.array([[matrix1[0], matrix1[1]], [matrix1[2], matrix1[3]])
n = np.array([[matrix2[0], matrix2[1]], [matrix2[2], matrix2[3]])
det1 = np.linalg.det(m)
det2 = np.linalg.det(n)
dot1 = np.vdot(m, n)
dot2 = np.vdot(n, m)
mat_product1 = np.matmul(m, n)
mat_product2 = np.matmul(n, m)
m_inv = np.linalg.inv(m)
n_inv = np.linalg.inv(n)
solve1 = np.dot(m_inv, n)
solve2 = np.dot(n_inv, m)

print("Matrix 1: ")
print(m)
print("Matrix 2: ")
print(n)
```

It says that matrix1 and matrix2 are unresolved variables:
[Unresolved reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtXZq.png)

When I tried it in the Python Console, I got this message:
[TypeError message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJoiN.png)

Is there any way around this, or is it not possible to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: I would really recommend that you start by factoring out a function like `get_2x2_matrix_from_user()`, which will handle all the input, accumulation into a list and subsequent transformation into a `np.ndarray` -- which you will just call twice.

Comment: Ignore the indents. I was too lazy to change them.
Also, I know that I can use \n to print the matrices on new lines with one print command each; I haven't got to that part yet because I'm condensing my code in order.

Comment: Sorry for that, it's my first question. I'll get to it rn.

Comment: Thanks @dedObed for your advice. I have removed the unnecessary indents. I'll get to trying out making a function to deal with this.

Comment: Once you have that function, you'll realize realize that all the other code (determinants etc.) is independent of your problem, so it can be removed :-)

Comment: My mistake was as simple as me forgetting a pair of square brackets.

Comment: Congrats for figuring it out! The question would still benefit from have the code limited to the [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll do this while condensing the rest of the code in my program.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that what I was trying has been correct all along, and my only mistake was forgetting to put a pair of square brackets.
So, this:

```
m = np.array([matrix1[0], matrix1[1]], [matrix1[2], matrix1[3]])
n = np.array([matrix2[0], matrix2[1]], [matrix2[2], matrix2[3]])
```

becomes this:

```
m = np.array([[matrix1[0], matrix1[1]], [matrix1[2], matrix1[3]]])
n = np.array([[matrix2[0], matrix2[1]], [matrix2[2], matrix2[3]]])
```